# How can i safely isolate on-line activity such as banking from chrome browser extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions, administrator

I have seen advice (from an earlier post) stating that simply running separate instances of chrome will not help, and that it is necessary to create separate windows users, one of which (user A) has a clean (no extensions) installation of chrome which can then be used for banking/other sensitive applications. An extended version of chrome run by another user (user B) would then be unable to view user A's browser content. Is this correct?

Further, is it safe for user A (but not user B) to be an administrator account?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/791327/do-chrome-extensions-for-one-user-have-any-access-to-other-users

Comment: @Alan All relevant information should be contained in your question or a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple actually.

If you start an Incognito section, the following happens:

- Your cookies are not available for that session, and any cookie set during that session is automatically deleted at the end.
- Your browser history is not affected the same way as cookies.
- Your extensions are not loaded. Some Chromium browsers allow specific extensions to be loaded in an Incognito window, and you have to specifically tell that from the extension page, but as far as I know, Chrome does not support this.

So the simple answer is, just open an incognito window and do your banking stuff in there and you're fine.

If security is your main concern, this is in any way the way to go. Using a separate user would save your stuff in that account, which then is vulnerable for tracking in the very same way.